# Approach to solve stock maximize in HackerRank?

Tags: c++

Here is the link to the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/stockmax which i am trying to solve.

My Approach:

Traverse from index 0 through n. If the price in the next day is more than current day, I buy shares. And if the price in the next day is lesser than current day, I sell already bought shares at current rate. However I couldn't pass test cases and don't know why my solution is wrong.

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int a[100005]={0};
int main()
    {
    int t,n;
    long long sum=0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
        {
        sum=0;
        int cnt=0;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>a[i];
        int i=0;
        while(i<n)
            {
            while(a[i+1]>=a[i]&&(i+1)<n)
                {
                sum-=a[i];
                i++;
                cnt++;
            }
            sum+=(cnt)*a[i];
            cnt=0;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%lld\n",max(sum,0));
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `a[i+1]` may contain data from previous test case. Be careful.

Comment: Thank you MikeCAT. I Understand that, and will rectify that error, once i get a working solution for a single test case :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of traversing from index 0 through n, traverse backwards i.e. n to index 0 & apply logic to get max values for selling.It's a linear sweep problem